# JS scope for merge sorting please help me understnad

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, mergesort

can someone please to help me understand why the first block of code works but the second does not? Was trying to solve the problem of merging to arrays in order. First one is the solution code and second was the code I came up with.
I can't get around why the i variable seems to stick around in the loops in the working one but in my code the arr1Item seems to disappear when trying to use it in the while loop?

```js
const gerry = [0,3,4,31] 
const machmoud = [4,6,30]

const mergeSort = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const mergedArr = [];
  //init Counters
  let i= 1
  let j= 1
  let arr1Item = arr1[0]
  let arr2Item = arr2[0]
  
  while(arr1Item || arr2Item){        
    if(arr1Item < arr2Item || !arr2Item){
      mergedArr.push(arr1Item)
      arr1Item = arr1[i]
      i++
    }
      else{
        mergedArr.push(arr2Item)
        arr2Item = arr2[j]
        j++
      }
    
  }
  return mergedArr
}

console.log(mergeSort(gerry, machmoud))
```

2nd set of code

```
const gerry = [0,3,4,31] 
const machmoud = [4,6,30]

const mergeSort = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const mergedArr = [];
  //init Counters
  let i= 0
  let j= 0
  let arr1Item = arr1[j]
  let arr2Item = arr2[i]
  
  while(arr1Item || arr2Item){        
    if(arr1Item < arr2Item || !arr2Item){
      mergedArr.push(arr1Item)
      i++
    }
      else{
        mergedArr.push(arr2Item)
        j++
      }
    
  }
  return mergedArr
}


console.log(mergeSort(gerry, machmoud))
```

This runs into an infinite loop.

Comment: Both implementations potentially go wrong when they have a zero in the input array. It certainly goes wrong when both input arrays start with a zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code (the second block) is that the loop never updates the value of `arr1Item` and `arr2Item`, and so the `while` condition can never evaluate to anything else than that it did the first time. Hence you get an infinite loop. So as soon as you change `i` or `j` should should also read the corresponding value from the array into the relevant variable.

However, there is also a problem that both implementations suffer from. If they would get two arrays which both have 0 as their first array value, or even if only the second array would start with 0, the results would not be as expected. You should really compare with `undefined`. Here is your code corrected:

```js
const gerry = [0, 3, 4, 31];
const machmoud = [4, 6, 30];

const mergeSort = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const mergedArr = [];
  //init Counters
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  let arr1Item = arr1[i];
  let arr2Item = arr2[j];

  while (arr1Item !== undefined || arr2Item !== undefined) {
    if (arr1Item < arr2Item || arr2Item === undefined) {
      mergedArr.push(arr1Item);
      i++;
      arr1Item = arr1[i];
    } else {
      mergedArr.push(arr2Item);
      j++;
      arr2Item = arr2[j];
    }
  }
  return mergedArr;
}

console.log(mergeSort(gerry, machmoud));
```

Comment: ok, so even though the i is updating, it is not updating the arr1item and arr2item variables to be evaluated for the for while loop. Is this an issue of scope because it still seems normal to me that because the i updates, it updates the variable from outside which are being evaluated to run the while loop. It's hard for me to make this an intuitive understanding even though I understand the reason it is not working.

Comment: Indeed. `i` is a variable on its own. It has nothing to do with the array. It is not because you once used `i` as an index for the array, that `i` somehow gets "linked" to that array. You can use that `i` for lots of things, but is does not get "married" with any other object or array, no matter how you use it. So every time you update the value of `i`, you need to "synchronise" any dependency that you think should be maintained.

Comment: ok, thanks for that explanation. I think I will need to see it a few more times to make it an instinct. One final thought: When I make a while loop should I automatically then assume that the variable (if it was a variable) that started the while loop needs to be re assigned inside of the while loop in order to to be able to change the condition and exit the loop?

Comment: If your while condition would have been `while (arr1[i] !== undefined || arr2[i] !== undefined)`, then you would not even need those `arr1Item` variables, and then you can just suffice with increasing `i` or `j`. That works, because the while condition will take the new value of `i` and perform a lookup of the corresponding value in `arr1`, ... *each* iteration.

Comment: The best thing you can do, is (1) use a debugger (the console) to monitor the values of the variables (`i`, `arr1Item`,...etc) during the step by step execution of your code. Really learn to work with this development tool. It belongs in the basic toolkit of a developer. Then (2) draw a memory map of what each variable has as value, or as reference. If you do it right, all doubts will disappear.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your time to lay that out. It is a lot more clear. Will endeavour to use the debugger more in these situations but even when seeing it in the debugger it can be hard to understand why it was not updating. But I basically understand now that I hardcoded it too early and repeatedly assess the hardcoded variable